# How do I get Visual Studio's "Publish Website" to 1. not overwrite web.config & 2. promote copies of dlls that were referenced from my GAC

Tags: visual-studio-2008, gac, publish

I started using a a library which I reference from the GAC during development. I want the dll included in the project bin directory when I promote it to the webserver. I also need my local and the server web.config to be different. Before I started using this library I really enjoyed using the publish website feature of VS. Now it just seems to be getting in the way.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the web.config deployment problem: Scott Guthrie wrote about here:

[**Tip/Trick: Automating Dev, QA, Staging, and Production Web.Config Settings with VS 2005**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/21/tip-trick-automating-dev-qa-staging-and-production-web-config-settings-with-vs-2005.aspx)

You can easily automate the configuration process within the Visual Studio build environment (and do so in a way that works both within the IDE, as well as with command-line/automated builds).

Answer (score 3):

Current configuration with the publish tool will send the web.config to the final site, and as far as I know there is no way around this.

Visual Studio 2010 is going to offer the ability to have targeted configurations allowing the deployment process to push out a different configuration.

As for the .dll reference, I believe the only way to get that to work is if you have "Copy Local" set to true on the reference.

Answer (score 2):

It's not ideal - splattne's answer is the correct way to set things up - but you can move it out of you project file ('Exclude From Project') and just keep it in your solution ('Solution Items' in VS2010).

This was it won't be copied when you publish.

Answer (score 0):

I found that making production Web.Config readonly on target server works fine when Publishing with Visual Studio 2010.

Hope this helps.